# mysql inner join interrogate 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have a table in a MySQL DB, called ‘users’. The fields for users are : id, email, username, first_name, last_name. Another table in the same MySQL DB, called ‘premium_users’ , contains 2 fields : user_id, premium_service_id. A third table called ‘premium_services’ contains 2 fields : premium_service_id , premium_service_name.

I want to create an SQL query , to interrogate my db, so i can have a full list of what premium services has every premium user. How can i interrogate properly with inner join? I’ve try this :

select * from users inner join premium_users on users.id = premium_users.user_id inner join premium_services on premium_users.premium_service_id = premium_services.premium_service_id;

Comment: Looks right. Have you tried it and run in to problems?

Comment: No ..i have no problems running but i don't know if is corect to show full list of what premium services has every premium user

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Since you say which service has every user, you'll need to use aggregation to determine this.  Here's one way:</strike>

```
select user_id
from premium_users
group by user_id 
having count(*) = (select count(*) from premium_services)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/225824/1)

Depending on your data, you may need `count(distinct premium_service_id)` instead, but you should have constraints that don't allow duplicates in those table.

Rereading your question, I might have got this backwards.  Looks like you want a list of premium services instead of users.  Same concept applies:

```
select ps.premium_service_id
from premium_services ps
  join premium_users pu on ps.premium_service_id = pu.premium_service_id
group by ps.premium_service_id
having count(distinct pu.user_id) = (select count(distinct user_Id) from premium_users)
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/225824/5)

Comment: I think he doesnt mean this. But nice approach :)

Comment: @SerifEmek -- perhaps you commented before seeing my edits?  Looks like OP is asking for a list of services that has every user.  This is one approach to doing that.

Comment: Both are perfect. But I am not sure if the question is about getting services which are used by all of the premium users. Yes, question looks like what you did but trial on the post is very different.

Comment: I don't understand Serif ..is to complicate your code...why don't you use inner join?

Comment: @DanutMarianGabrian - the title of your post doesn't have much to do with your actual question which involves aggregation (`group by`) rather than `inner joins`.  This should work for you though.  Have you tried it?